# XMLAttribute Query

Tags: xml, powershell

I have an XML as follows:

```xml
<start>
<start1>data1</start1>
<start.List>data2</start.List>
</start>
```

I have been able to access all the nodes/attributes values via the following via PowerShell

```bsh
[xml]$xmlFile = Get-Content path/to/xmlfile
$xmlFile.start
$xmlfile.start.start1
```

How do I view contents under `start.List`, it doesn't yield any result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use **quotes** because the name contains a dot:

```
$xmlFile.start.'start.List'
```